# Set split agents location to original agents location

Tags: split, anylogic, agent

I am trying to simulate the arrival of trucks to a warehouse, which delivers pallets that need to be stored. Forklifts are supposed to come to the trucks, one at a time, to offload them. In essence, forklift A should be assigned to truck 1, forklift A should offload individual pallets from truck 1. There will be 10 pallets on each incoming truck, therefore the forklifts should make 10 trips between the trucks and the storage bin in the warehouse.

To accomplish this, I am trying to use the split function, which splits incoming trucks to generate the pallet agents. Where I'm failing is that the split function only allows for the location of the split agents to be defined explicitly. This does not work, because the trucks are being pulled into unoccupied bays, using the "seize resource" block. The individual loading bays in this instance are represented by static resources. When perusing available examples on any logic website, the "on copy exit" action box in the split itself always contains "agent.setNetworkNode(original.bay);" but when I insert this code I get an error that says it is not defined for that agent type. I have searched the models and they don't initialize or set anything along these lines?

What this boils down to, is that the trucks are supposed to pull into a bay (which they are doing perfectly), pull a forklift to its bay to unload pallets individually, before being sent along the exit path out of the facility.

How can I ensure that the agents that are being generated by the split function, are placed at the exact location of the truck agent that they are being split off?

This is my error code : "Description: The method setnetworknode(RectangularNode) is undefined for the type agentPallet. Location: Model/Main/split - Split"

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "Split", imo. When the truck arrives, it should create 10 Pallet agents and `inject(10)` them into a "Source" block creating pallets. Specify the trucks bay location (which you should probably store as a variable in the truck) and set it as the initial location for your `Pallet` agent in the "Source" object.

Now, your pallets can seize forklifts as they see fit.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming a create a secondary logic flow for the pallets, how would you ensure that forklifts are assigned to trucks and not pallets? In other words, how do you ensure that all the forklift don't follow each other as theres 10 pallets and 10 forklifts?

Comment: If pallet agents seize forklifts, forklifts will go to pallets, not trucks. Why would they be assigned to trucks? They have nothing to do with trucks :)

Comment: With reference to your first reply, how does one save a location as a variable and then input that as the source?

Comment: that is a good ... new question ;-) (SOF is not a discussion board but more a knowledge base)

Comment: Aye aye Captain, I am composing a new question now. Thanks!